# iOS measuring objects

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

I am wondering if my math foo is just off.

Say I have a `UIView` that is 758.0 wide. I have a method that will then put labels within that UIView. I pass an NSArray with string objects for `UILabel` text - one array has 3 objects, one has 4. The first `UILabel` always has a width of 180.0. I want the remaining space of the `UIView` to be divided evenly amongst the remaining array objects. So I do this:

```
float space = (UIView.frame.size.width-180)/(NSArray.count-1);
```

but when create the remaining 2 or 3 `UILabel`s I am always short some space. Am I not accounting for padding or something?

Here's the output from my console:

```
2013-01-29 12:16:57.923 EUS Calculator[5388:c07] 758.000000::180.000000::578.000000::272.500000
2013-01-29 12:16:57.925 EUS Calculator[5388:c07] 758.000000::180.000000::578.000000::272.500000
2013-01-29 12:16:57.928 EUS Calculator[5388:c07] 758.000000::180.000000::578.000000::176.166672
2013-01-29 12:16:57.929 EUS Calculator[5388:c07] 758.000000::180.000000::578.000000::176.166672
2013-01-29 12:16:57.929 EUS Calculator[5388:c07] 758.000000::180.000000::578.000000::176.166672
```

first number is width of `UIView`, second is width of first `UILabel`, third is remaining space and 4th is the remaining space/number of remaining `UILabels`.

Comment: It would help if you explained what is wrong with the output you are showing. What values do you expect for the 4th value in the output? You say you are short some space. Be more specific.

Comment: (758 - 180) / 3 = 192.67 and (758 - 180) / 2 = 289. Can we see your actual code?

Comment: are you sure you're short? set the background of the UILabel to pink to see exactly where they are being placed